# setOnClickListener is not showing in intellij

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

`setOnClickListener` is not showing in intellij even the textview names I can't write them without `R.id.the_name`.

[image]

What is going wrong?

Comment: `R.id.name1` is just the id of a view, not the view itself. It's an Int.

Comment: Please share your code in the post as formatted text, not as an image.

Answer (score 3):

This is not how android works. It seems you miss the very basics.

R.id.button is just an Int, the id of a view. To get the view you can do `findViewById(id)` for example.

So then in your case maybe:

```
val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)
button.setOnClickListener {
    //on click
}
```

Comment: it worked thank you so much i am learning it by myself and i didn't see this step before thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should implement view binding to your projects.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

So instead of `val btn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.yourbuttonId)` you can `val btn = binding.yourbuttonId`